# How can I make drop down lists keep the last selected option in flutter when moving to another screen

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I have these filters in my flutter app 
I need a way to keep the last selected options 
[drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lshZm.png)

```
Ddl(
    name: 'Type',
    initialValue: _type,
    onSelect: (str) {
        setState(() {
            _type = str;
        });
    },
)
```

here is my ddl code

```
DropdownButton<String>(
        isExpanded: true,
        value: selectedValue,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
        iconSize: 24,
        elevation: 16,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        underline: Container(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = newValue;
          });
          widget.onSelect(newValue);
        },
        items: _getList(this.widget.name),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to retain values across screens is by keeping them inside a class with static variable with getter and setter. Every time the dropdown value changes you also set this static variable. Upon screen load, you would read these values and initialise the widget.

```
class dropDownModel {
  static int last_selected_value;

  static int get_last_selected_value() {
    return last_selected_value;
  }

  static void set_last_selected_value(int Value) {
    last_selected_value = Value;
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean like that ``` 
                                        initialValue: DropDownModel
                                            .getLastSelectedValue(),
                                        onSelect: (str) {
                                          setState(() {
                                          
                                            DropDownModel.setLastSelectedValue(
                                                str);
                                       
                                      ) ``` it didnt work